# Spyder complains about some basic commands

Tags: python, spyder

Here is some code that runs with no problem:

[image]

When I hover over the warning triangles, Spyder tells me that `datetime` and `vstack` are "undefined".  But they seem to be defined, since the code runs.  How can I make those warning triangles go away?

Copy-able code here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#%%
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 1, 2])
this_year = datetime.date.today().year
y = vstack((x,x))
#%%
```

Comment: Try to avoid using screen shots of code.

Comment: @redFIVE, thanks for the pointer ... but isn't this a good use of a screen shot, considering the function of illustrating the warning triangles?

Comment: Its not the end of the world, but it just helps if someone wants to recreate it themselves they just have to copy + paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime and use np.vstack
```

You have not imported the `datetime` module and `vstack` is part of `numpy` which you imported as `np`.

I don't see how the code could run without importing datetime and using np.vstack.

Typing the commands into ipython gives `NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined`:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: x = np.array([0,1,2])

In [5]: this_year = datetime.date.today().year
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a5c59948ea66> in <module>()
----> 1 this_year = datetime.date.today().year

NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

your code runs because I think there is a `site-packages/spyderlib/scientific_startup.py` that imports modules automatically, `numpy` is included as must `datetime`.

Comment: you got it!  Regarding your question, it definitely worked without those things.  Maybe Spyder does some things automatically in the background, but still warns for good form?

Comment: Must be some automatic imports in Spyder but better to get in the habit of importing your modules as that won't be the case usually! Maybe the `#%%` the code is wrapped in has something to do with it.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) We deactivated automatic imports in our upcoming release to avoid this kind of confusions. We are also planning to add a tutorial about how to use Spyder correctly in a future release.